# apple-app-site-association can't handle links with # character

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

I'm trying to set up restrictive applinks for an application, however we only want specific links to route to the app, the rest to open in Safari directly (without a passthrough).

In order to do this, I'm using the following json file. However, it seems to work fine for https://domain.com/test, but fails on https://domain.com/#/test

If I add "*" to the list of paths, it works fine, but then we're letting **everything** through, which creates a poor experience if the app can't support that link.

Has anyone gotten something like this to work? It seems bizarre to me that apple can't handle routing for links that contain the '#' character. Our website uses the # character in all of our routing, and

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [{
            "appID": "TEAMID.BUNDLEID",
            "paths":[ "/test", "/*/test", "/*/test/*", "*/test/*" ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same problem. It's because of `#` contained in url route.

The best way to solve it is to remove `#` from every url route.

However, if you cannot remove it. You have to use `*` for the list of paths.

In this case, you might handle unsupported path by gracefully fallback to Safari.

It would be something like this.

- if user tap at supported paths. `OtherApp->MyApp`
- if user tap at unsupported paths. `OtherApp->MyApp->Safari`

Comment: Removing # isn't really an option with Angular. We ended up creating other routes that redirect to the desired url with # in the path

Comment: I think universal link doesn't work with redirect link.